# Joomla 2.5 with gantry doesn't work in IE9

Tags: joomla, frameworks, joomla2.5

Im using Joomla 2.5 with gantry framework and my template doesn't working on IE9. The logo is the only part loaded.

The problem:
http://www.wmi9.com.br/aprova/

Does anyone know what can be?
Thanks!

Comment: the site looks the same on ie9 as it does on chrome/firefox to me. can you provide a screenshot to demonstrate your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the slideshow the console showing a few errors:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.wmi9.com.br 
from frame with URL http://player.vimeo.com/video/2203727?wmode=transparent. 
Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Try to remove the VIMEO and YOUTUBE slides.

Comment: Do you have zoom in the browser? Because it loos OK to everyone besides you mate.

Answer (score 0):

Load perfectly in IE 9.0.8 on 64bit.

Interestingly enough, I have had an issue where the problem is not with IE itself. But with all the plugins and toolbars installed that it affects the page.

Comment: Interessing... here I'm using IE9.0.8 in Windows 64 bit and the problem persists... thanks for the tip! but unfortunately it did not work :(